# Can the Archivist use the Dark Knowledge feature to benefit himself too?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature

Can the Archivist (from *Heroes of Horror*) use the Dark Knowledge feature to benefit himself too?

For example, say an archivist uses Dark Knowledge to boost the attack rolls of his party. Would the archivist get this bonus too?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The benefits of dark knowledge also apply to the archivist

The *Player's Handbook* General Guidelines and Glossary on [**ally**](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_ally&alpha=) says, "A creature friendly to you. In most cases, references to 'allies' include yourself" (304). As the archivist special ability **dark knowledge**, in part, says that the archivist grants "his allies benefits against the creatures they face" (*Heroes of Horror* 83) and does *not* say that the ability exclude the archivist herself, the archivist benefits from her own dark knowledge ability just like the rest of her allies.